# Compare parameter of type Any

Tags: swift

I have a object called **message.body** of type **Any**

The object returns ***nil*** but if I do some test equals nil, it says that message.body ALWAYS been true.

[image]

[image]

How I solve this?

***EDIT***

Thank you for all answers

This is my code:

```
extension FirstViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "jsHandler" {
            print( "Value: " )
            if message.body != nil {
                print( message.body )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Really is a strong type this Any of message.body.

Thank you very much @vacawama, I really researched the subject but did not find anything the way I researched.

Comment: In this case you are testing equality with `Optional<Any>.none` and since it seems `message.body` is not an optional `Any`, it will come as always `true`. That should teach you to use `Any` only in exceptional cirmcumstances.

Comment: Is `message.body` an object whose type you defined, or something from an external library?

Comment: Also, please add the actual code to your question, not just images.

Comment: The warning clearly says that `message.body` is non-optional, it cannot be `nil` but it can be `"nil"`. And `message.body` is most likely something more specific than `Any`. Don't fight the strong type system.

Comment: You should avoid using Any unless it’s some old legacy objective-c code. Better change it on enumeration of your needs.

Comment: Hey @JohnMontgomery, I edit with the code. Thank you man!

Comment: Thank you very much @vacawama, I really researched the subject but did not find anything the way I researched.

Comment: Hey @Sulthan, really is this! I will study more about exceptional cirmcuntances! Your tip and mark of vacawama help me about my problem!